# Install new python version using virtual venv in linux

Tags: python, linux, debian, virtualenv

I know there are some solutions in the internet but I couldn't find an end to end solution and I am pretty skeptical about doing things wrong so asking here for a complete solution.

I have recently installed debian10 and it comes with python2.7 and python3.7. I want to install python3.6 but not as a new python but as an isolated one using virtualenv (that I got from internet as I have python3.7 and venv can only install the same python version).

I couldn't understand that do I need to install python3.6 first in my system and then use virtualenv or I can directly install virtualenv using pip3 (I prefer pip) of python3 and install it. Also in either of the cases do I need to somehow fetch the source code for python3.6 and if yes then do I need to build it locally first then use virtualenv or not. A detailed step wise solution will be better along with if any changes need to done in the .bashrc file.

I am new in Linux and python environment and still learning. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

P.S.: If you find that I need to explain more or you need some clarifications kindly comment it instead of down voting first. I will try my best to modify my question accordingly.

Comment: `virtualenv` is a specific tool for *using* a particolar Python version, but it doesn't help with installing several parallel versions. Raybe look at `pyenv`; but understand that its concept of environments is different.

Comment: So, I have python3.7. Can I make a virtual environment inside it running python3.6?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. A virtual environment is not "inside" any Python version or executable, it *uses* one, conceretely by updating your `PATH` to include a directory which contains a symbolic link to the Python version you want to use, which shadows the system-wide `python` executable. If you have `/usr/local/bin/python3.6` you can easily create a virtual environment which uses that as `python` but it doesn't provide any tools for installing that Python version there.

Comment: Okay, that means creating a virtual environment is like copying the files of an existing python installed in my system but it runs in an isolated manner so that I can have multiple copies of the same python version which doesn't interfere with each other.